Why does culture not change in Blazor Web App while running in Start without debugging mode?
I'm pretty much a newbie when it comes to Blazor. I want to implement multi-language in my Blazor web app(Blazor United) in InteractiveAuto render mode.
I followed this tutorial:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/globalization-localization?view=aspnetcore-8.0#interactive-auto-components
The tutorial is quite long, so I can't post all my code.
After following everything in the tutorial, the code ran successfully.
However, the default language in my program is not English. I set my default language in advance in this piece of code in program.cs.
 var supportedCultures = new[] { "zh-hans","en" };
 var localizationOptions = new RequestLocalizationOptions()
     .SetDefaultCulture(supportedCultures[0])
     .AddSupportedCultures(supportedCultures)
     .AddSupportedUICultures(supportedCultures);
 app.UseRequestLocalization(localizationOptions);
 app.MapControllers();

And here is my code to test it in MainLayout:
@inherits LayoutComponentBase
@inject IStringLocalizer<MainLayout> Localizer
@inject Blazored.LocalStorage.ISyncLocalStorageService LocalStorage
@code {   
    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {        
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("zh-hans");
        CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("zh-hans");                 }        
        abc = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.ToString();
    }    
    string abc { get; set; } = "456";
}


<div class="page">
    <div class="sidebar">
        <div>@abc</div>
    </div>

    <main>
        <div class="top-row px-4">
            <a href="https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/" target="_blank">About</a>
        </div>        
        <article class="content px-4">
            @Body
        </article>
    </main>
</div>

<div id="blazor-error-ui" style="display:flex;">
    @Localizer["AnUnhandledErrorHasOccurred"]
    <a href="" class="reload"> @Localizer["Reload"]</a>
    <a class="dismiss"></a>
</div>

But I found a strange problem, when the program is running in Start Debugging mode, everything is normal. However, when I run it in Start Without Debugging mode, the default language is forcibly changed to English.
I even added this piece of code to MainLayout:
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
     CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("zh-hans");
     CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("zh-hans");
}

But language still cannot be changed. What causes this? I run it in Start Without Debugging mode for the convenience of using hot reload. How can I solve this problem?

Do you set some variable for environment to modify them? I mean production or debug?

@BrandoZhang Never, it is a blank new project and I test the localization first but not do anything else.

@BrandoZhang Are there any environment variables that will affect culture? If so, please tell me. At least I checked that no relevant variables are set in appsetting.json.

@BrandoZhang I just updated the code of how I tested it, please take a look.

what's the Browser Language Preferences Accept-Language inside the request when you are testing with non debug mode?

@BrandoZhang In debug mode it is zh-CN,zh;q=0.9. When in without debug mode it is en,en-US;q=0.9,zh;q=0.8,zh-CN;q=0.7. It seems that there is a difference between the two, but I did not add code to control culture through Accept-Language.

Actually this is browser prefer language inside your computer, but you still could set it by statically set the client-side culture like this article said.

@BrandoZhang It doesn't work either I set the applicationCulture to "zh-hans" or set the DefaultThreadCurrentCulture/DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture to zh-hans.

@BrandoZhang Hello, is there any way that I can solve this problem? Or do I need to provide a minimum sample?

Please give me a minimum sample to reproduce the issue at my side to test .

@BrandoZhang Here is the sample. Please have a look:https://github.com/kyuranger/BlazorTest

Many days later, I accidentally discovered the problem.
In App.razor, the default value is:
<html lang="en">

After I modify it to:
<html lang="@CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.ToString()">

But I found this way only works in some browsers (not all browsers).
And then I found another way:
var supportedCultures = new[] { "zh-Hans", "en-us" };
var localizationOptions = new RequestLocalizationOptions()
    .SetDefaultCulture(supportedCultures[0])
    .AddSupportedCultures(supportedCultures)
    .AddSupportedUICultures(supportedCultures);
localizationOptions.AddInitialRequestCultureProvider(new CustomRequestCultureProvider(async context =>
{
    return await Task.FromResult(new ProviderCultureResult("zh-Hans"));
}));

The most important is this line:
 localizationOptions.AddInitialRequestCultureProvider(new CustomRequestCultureProvider(async context =>
 {
     return await Task.FromResult(new ProviderCultureResult("zh-Hans"));
 }));

